# Loading contents when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below html table

```html
<table id="label" style="width: 100%;">
 <tr id="tr">
  <td class='td'>
   <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
   <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
  </td>
  <td class='td'>
   <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="tr">
  <td class='td'>

   <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Communications' second year</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
  <td class='td'>
   <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="tr">
  <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
  <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="tr">
  <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
  <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="tr">
  <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
  <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I don't want to render all the rows at once. I need to display only 10 rows at a time and when the user scrolls, the vertical scroll bar then again I need to add 10 more rows to the existing 10 rows and so on.

Basically I have all static html rows and I need to render a few and then add few more on scroll. How can I do that?

Comment: The id attribute is to mark only one element in DOM. Use class for many elements.

Comment: Where's your jQuery / javascript? What have you tried?

Comment: i've searched a lot and tried two methods but couldn't find a proper one yet!

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it's a static page I think you can display the first 10 rows and hide the others.. Then using JS/Jquery, you need to check whether your scroll bar reaches the bottom of the page. You could using something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
       //shows the next 10 rows here
   }
});
```

Comment: If its not at the bottom of the page you can get `offset()` of the table add `height()` of the table and `if (window.scrollY >= $('table').offSet().x + $('table').height())` show the next 10

Comment: Yup, it depends on the situation.. This is a high level solution.. ^^

Comment: below the line //shows the next 10 rows here should i write something? or that's all the coding or what? :( could you explain more details please

Comment: You need to change it into some code that might show the next 10 rows.. I use a comment there because I don't know exactly how you try to show/hide the rows. However, that part is kinda trivial for me, so I leave it to you..

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function( ) {
  var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop( )
  if (wScroll > ($('.class').offset.Top - ($(window).height / 1.2) {
    $('.class').css({'opacity': '1');
  }
};
```

CSS

```
.class {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Change '.class' to any name you want and add it to the elements you want to add the effect to. Also to control when it fades in you can change the if statement.